# Using takeUntil to complete an RxJS stream

Tags: javascript, rxjs, system.reactive, redux-observable

I want to complete an inner stream that doesn't naturally complete, using the `takeUntil` operator, like this:

```
  outerObservable
    .mergeMap(() => {
        innerObservable
            .takeUntil(stopObservable$)
    });
```

This works, the inner stream completes as expected, but I would like for the outer stream to return one last value after the stop signal. Even after lots of googling, I still don't know how.

EDIT:

I've written an operator that seems to do the trick, but leaving the question open because I know there's a better way or something I'm completely misunderstanding.

```js
function takeUntilThen(notifier, oneLastValue) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(subscriber => {
        var source = this;
        notifier.subscribe(() => {
            subscriber.next(oneLastValue);
            subscriber.complete()
        });
        return source.subscribe(value => {
            subscriber.next(value);
        },
        err => subscriber.error(err),
        () => subscriber.complete());
    });
}
```

Comment: careful, your operator leaks its notifier subscription!

Comment: thanks, I'll look into that - when I figure out what it means :-)

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want to race between `innerObservable` and `stopObservable` and Whichever wins, should be able to output *something*.

You can use the aptly named `.race()` operator for this, instead of using `.takeUntil()`. See the example in the redux-observable docs recipe on Cancellation:

https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/Cancellation.html#cancel-and-do-something-else-eg-emit-a-different-action

```
const somethingEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(SOMETHING)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      innerObservable
        .race(
          stopObservable
            .take(1)
        )
    );
```

Since your example is pseudo code, here's one that's more concrete:

```
import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

const fetchUserEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      ajax.getJSON(`/api/users/${action.payload}`)
        .map(response => fetchUserFulfilled(response))
        .race(
          action$.ofType(FETCH_USER_CANCELLED)
            .map(() => incrementCounter())
            .take(1)
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will this work when the inner observable never completes naturally? I had a look and a play about with that solution provided in the redux-observable docs, but it didn't work for my case.

Comment: @mysomic can you explain what you mean by "never completes naturally"?

Comment: In that example, the ajax stream only ever returns a single value and then completes. My stream (that I have in the exact same place) returns many values as events happen and it never completes (naturally). Therefore, to my mind at least, there can't be a race... at least I figure that's why that example doesn't work for my particular case :-) I've gotten it working fine using the ajax stream in the example

Comment: When using `.race()`, the winner is the _first_ to emit something. The winner can continue to emit, but the loser is unsubscribed. It sounds like maybe you're saying you don't want it to be winner vs. loser because you want the stopObservable to be able to stop the innerObservable even after innerObservable has emitted many things, more inline with what takeUntil lets you do?

Comment: If that's the case, I would need to know what innerObservable and stopObservable are emitting to give a recommendation. It _might_ be ideal to use `takeUntil(stopObservable)` normally and just listen to the same stopObservable again in another epic or using `merge()`

Comment: Listening to the same stopObservable is a no-go because one of the merged stop observables is the start observable. I.E when something happens, fire up the inner observable. If it happens again, then shut down inner before firing it up again.

Comment: I need to know what innerObservable and stopObservable are or at least an equivalent simplified example of the behavior of them.

Comment: thanks for taking the time on this @jayphelps - The code is here - http://jsbin.com/tofilaz/edit?js